# CORS issue in codeigniter 4: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: php, reactjs, axios, codeigniter-4

I'm making an api with Codeigniter 4 for a react application. Everything works fine in postman but when I make requests with axios (also tried fetch), it gets CORS error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/testpost' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I tried adding headers to base controller:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```

Now it works fine with requests without JSON body, but when I send json body same error occurs.

```
axios.post("http://localhost:8080/testpost", { data: "test" })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("error!!!");
    });
```

```
// Routes.php
$routes->post('/testpost', 'Home::testPost');
```

```
// Home Controller
public function testPost()
{
    return $this->response->setJSON('test response');
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try by setting Apache response headers and redirect method to `.htaccess` in root of `www/public` directory, like this:

```
#Redirect for CORS Preflight request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
#Set headers to access CORS Requests / allowing localhost only
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

NOTE: Be careful by adding `Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` to your `.htaccess`, `"*"` open doors for attackers, replace `*` with your domain or subdumain!

Comment: Is there any problem with this solution?

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately it's not working. It is doing the same thing as setting headers in PHP.

Comment: If it's done then can you please mark this as "Done"?

Comment: Thanks, now it works. I hoped a PHP way for this. but for now I think this is the best way.

Comment: How *exactly* do you set Apache response headers? `httpd.conf`?

Comment: @ron_g , you must add these lines to `.htaccess` file in your root public path. and be careful to not duplicate first 3 lines.

Comment: Added this in the mode_rewrite.c, it worked. I used only `Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "content-type"` because I'm not sending any headers. No other changes in the front end.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is because fonts are blocked due to [www.yourdomain.com](http://www.yourdomain.com), then put these lines in your .htaccess file

```
# Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Default folder of CodeIgniter already contain complete .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Add the given code to your construct method.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if($method == "OPTIONS") {
  die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your index.php on public directory, just paste the following codes to set

```
headers for the response
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if($method == "OPTIONS") {
die();
}
```

just before the response area[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi i know it's a little late but I want to share my solution to this particular issue since I didn't find any answer online that satisfied my taste. I created a controller to handle preflight and created a route for the options request to point to my preflight controller

Steps:

1. Make a controller to handle preflight requests, I named mine "Preflight"

   `php spark make:controller PreFlight`
2. Add the following code to create an options method for your preflight controller

```
    public function options()
    {
      return $this->response->setStatusCode(200);
    }
```

3. Create a route to handle the preflight's OPTIONS request

   `$routes->options('(:any)', 'Preflight::options');`

Hope this helps for anyone going through the same issue