# Codeigniter 4 restful api return cors error when using authorization bearer token

Tags: reactjs, axios, jwt, cors, codeigniter-4

On the frontend I'm using react and sending the request via axios

```
import axios from "axios";

import { getToken } from "./auth";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL,
});

api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const token = getToken();

  if (token && config && config?.headers) {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }

  return config;
});

export default api;
```

And in backend i'm using codeigniter 4. But when add a authorization bearer token in request, return cors error.

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/v1/user' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

```
<?php

namespace App\Filters;

use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;

class Cors implements FilterInterface
{
    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
        $origin = base_api();

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$origin}");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin,X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Requested-Method, Authorization");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT, DELETE");

        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

        if($method == "OPTIONS") {
            die();
        }
    }

    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Has anyone had a similar error?

I've looked everywhere for a solution, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS issue in codeigniter 4: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61925666/cors-issue-in-codeigniter-4-response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-c)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa didn't solve.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just learning authentication in React with Maximilian Schwarzmüller's udemy course and I think that you just need to split the taken token from client and check like below.
I don't know how to implement by php but ı hope js implementation help you.

```
    function checkAuthMiddleware(req, res, next) {
      if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        return next();
      }
      if (!req.headers.authorization) {
        console.log('NOT AUTH. AUTH HEADER MISSING.');
        return next(new NotAuthError('Not authenticated.'));
      }
      const authFragments = req.headers.authorization.split(' ');
    
      if (authFragments.length !== 2) {
        console.log('NOT AUTH. AUTH HEADER INVALID.');
        return next(new NotAuthError('Not authenticated.'));
      }
      const authToken = authFragments[1];
      try {
        const validatedToken = validateJSONToken(authToken);
        req.token = validatedToken;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('NOT AUTH. TOKEN INVALID.');
        return next(new NotAuthError('Not authenticated.'));
      }
      next();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
<?php

namespace App\Filters;

use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;

class Cors implements FilterInterface
{
    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
        if (array_key_exists('HTTP_ORIGIN', $_SERVER)) {
            $origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
        } else if (array_key_exists('HTTP_REFERER', $_SERVER)) {
            $origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        } else {
            $origin = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }

        $allowed_domains = array(
            'http://localhost:8080',
            'http://localhost:3000',
        );

        if (in_array($origin, $allowed_domains)) {
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin);
        }

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-API-KEY, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, observe, enctype, Content-Length, X-Csrf-Token");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
        header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
        header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        if ($method == "OPTIONS") {
            header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK CORS");
            die();
        }
    }

    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).