# Codeigniter 4 restful api return cors error when using PUT and DELETE method

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors, codeigniter-4

On the frontend I'm using react and sending the request via axios.

```
import axios from "axios";

import { getToken } from "./auth";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL,
});

export default api;
```

And in backend i'm using codeigniter 4. But when send a PUT or DELETE request, return cors error. POST and GET work fine. In postman, PUT and DELETE work fine too.

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/v1/finance/1' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

My Codeigniter 4 filters config.

```
<?php

namespace App\Filters;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;

class Cors implements FilterInterface
{
    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
        $origin = base_api();

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$origin}");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin,X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Requested-Method, Authorization");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT, DELETE");

        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

        if($method == "OPTIONS") {
            die();
        }
    }

    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Filters.php

```
<?php

namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\CSRF;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\DebugToolbar;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\Honeypot;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\InvalidChars;
use CodeIgniter\Filters\SecureHeaders;
use App\Filters\Cors;
use App\Filters\AuthFilter;

class Filters extends BaseConfig
{
    public $aliases = [
        'csrf'          => CSRF::class,
        'toolbar'       => DebugToolbar::class,
        'honeypot'      => Honeypot::class,
        'invalidchars'  => InvalidChars::class,
        'secureheaders' => SecureHeaders::class,
        'authFilter'    => AuthFilter::class,
        'cors'          => Cors::class,
    ];

    public $globals = [
        'before' => [
            'cors'
        ],
        'after' => [
            'toolbar'
        ],
    ];

    public $methods = [];

    public $filters = [];
}
```

[Devtools error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FiEI.png)

[Devtools preflight error 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCaNV.png)

.htaccess

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

    #Set headers to access CORS Requests / allowing localhost only
    Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
    Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    # RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

Has anyone had a similar error?

I've looked everywhere for a solution, but I couldn't find it.

I try change .htaccess and set a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`, but not working.

Comment: A preflight response must have a status in the 2xx range for preflight to succeed. CORS middleware typically respond with 403 when preflight fails, but a 404 response indicates that CORS isn't configured at all in your app. You should edit your question and show the code where you actually activate/stack that `FilterInterface`.

Comment: @jub0bs I put the part of the filter that you commented.

Comment: See if putting `use App\Filters\Cors;` at the top, even before `use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;`, improves things.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: What about moving `'cors' => Cors::class,` to the top of your aliases?

Comment: Nothing, still error =(

Answer (score -1):

Hi i answered this issue on another thread. Check it out and see if it works for you. It handles the solution by making a route to handle the OPTIONS request.
[Solve preflight error on CI4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77904472)

Step 1. Create a preflight controller.

Step 2. Create a controller method in your preflight controller to handle options request and return a 200 http response code on execution

```
`return $this->response->setStatusCode(200);`
```

Step 3. Create a route to capture the preflight request and point it to your preflight controller

```
`$routes->options('(:any)','Preflight::options');`
```

Hope this helpes anyone going through this same issue.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Added the essential parts. Hope that helps you and anyone else looking for the solution @steven7mwesigwa